# Efficient database search?

Tags: mysql, database, search

I'm creating a script which queries a server for the logged-in clients and then for each client checks if they (their id) is registered in the database.

Assume the clients with ID: 1, 3 and 5 are logged in. The database has only registered clients with ID 1,2,3 and 4. Client 5 is thus new to the system and needs to be registered into the database.

My question is how to do this in an efficient manner? Taking the client ID's one-by-one and search the database each time is no doubt the easiest approach, but how efficient is this? Are there ways to do this differently in order to minimize execution time and database load?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you set the new client's ID to 5 ? Maybe when you do that is a good time to register it instead of running a script later.

Comment: @X.L.Ant can't do that unfortunately. The program is 3rd party and the script I am writing uses the programs telnet query feature to get data.